# Add zero in between values in column (dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
  ID  Date   Volume Sales
  1  20191   3.33    1.33
  1  20192   3.33    1.33
  1  20193   3.33    1.33
  1  20194   2.66     2
  1  20195   2.66     2
  1  20196   2.66     2
  1  20197    2      2.66
  1  20198    2      2.66
  1  20199    2      2.66
  1  201910    1.33   3.33
  1  201911    1.33   3.33
  1  201912   1.33   3.33
```

I would like to add a 0 right after the year 2019 in this case to that the date looks like: 201901 etc while 201910 and above remains the same.

My initial thought process is to use;

```
 np.where(df['Date'].str.len() == 5,
```

where if string equals 5, we add the zero. Otherwise, data stays the same.

Expected output:

```
  ID  Date   Volume Sales
  1  201901   3.33    1.33
  1  201902   3.33    1.33
  1  201903   3.33    1.33
  1  201904   2.66     2
  1  201905   2.66     2
  1  201906   2.66     2
  1  201907    2      2.66
  1  201908    2      2.66
  1  201909    2      2.66
  1  201910    1.33   3.33
  1  201911    1.33   3.33
  1  201912    1.33   3.33
```

Comment: Are you going to use the 'Date' column as actual dates? Then it may be more convenient to immediately convert that column into a year and month date, instead of editing the string.

Comment: Is that possible with these set of dates? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are strings:

```
df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 6 else f"{x[:4]}0{x[-1]}")
```

But I concur that you should convert to proper dates, as suggested by @0 0 in the comment.

Comment: Do you have a solution for converting to normal dates? From week format.

Comment: What do you mean by weekly dates? The last digits are weeks? Looks like months to me...

Comment: Last digits are weeks, correct. So 201901 to 201952 , in YearWeek format

Comment: You should ask another question concerning the date conversion. Use the tag `pandas` to attract the pandas experts